# How to select and remove multiple pages in wagtail admin?

Tags: django, wagtail

In django admin we can select multiple items and then delete them in one action. Is that possible in the wagtail admin or should we delete pages one by one?

Comment: Not yet it seems: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/121

Comment: ok thanks @solarissmoke. I think I should use the django admin for this kind of stuff.